# How to typecheck a property with a class decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, python-typing

I'm struggling to get this code to properly type check with `mypy`:

```
from typing import Any

class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, func) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

class Foo:
    @property
    @Decorator
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42

f = Foo()
# reveal_type(f.foo)
a: int = f.foo
print(a)
```

This gives me this error, even though running it correctly prints `42` (note I've uncommented the `reveal_type` when running `mypy`):

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:17: note: Revealed type is "mypy_test.test.Decorator"
test.py:18: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Decorator", variable has type "int")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

This code properly type checks with `mypy`:

```
from typing import Any

class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, func) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

class Foo:
    @property
    @Decorator
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42

f = Foo()
# reveal_type(f.foo)
a: int = f.foo()
print(a)
```

But this obviously won't run correctly:

```
$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gsgx/code/tmp/mypy_test/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    a: int = f.foo()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Note that if instead of using a class decorator I use a function decorator, everything works fine (runs correctly and no typecheck errors, `reveal_type` now shows `f.foo` is `Any`):

```
def Decorator(f):
    return f
```

How can I get this to work using a class decorator? I'm using Python 3.10.6 and mypy 0.991.

Answer (score 3):

`Decorator.__call__` hides the type hints that you provided for `foo`, and replaces them with uselessly general hints.

You need to use `typing.ParamSpec` and `typing.TypeVar` to capture the hints of the decorated function to reuse for the new one. I'm not entirely sure how to do that for your class, but here's an example using ordinary functions:

```
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar


P = ParamSpec('P')
RV = TypeVar('R')


def Decorator(f: Callable[P, RV]) -> Callable[P, RV]:
    def _(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> RV:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _
```

`typing.ParamSpec` is available starting in Python 3.11, though you can get it from the 3rd-party `typing-extensions` package as well.

---

The problem with the class is that you seem to need to make `Decorator` generic in order to associate the return value of the argument to `__init__` with the return value of `__call__`:

```
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVar, Generic


P = ParamSpec('P')
RV = TypeVar('R')


class Decorator(Generic[RV]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[P, RV]) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> RV:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

This "works", but requires you to use `typing.cast` with

```
a: int = cast(int, f.foo)
```

to avoid

```
tmp.py:27: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Decorator[int]", variable has type "int")  [assignment]
```

Perhaps there's a simpler solution for the class itself that I'm overlooking. It seems to me, though, that `mypy` simply isn't recognizing that `f.foo` and `Foo.foo` should have different types.

---

On the other hand, a seemingly trivial change

```
class Foo:
    @Decorator
    def foo2(self) -> int:
        return 42

    foo = property(foo2)
```

changes the revealed type of `f.foo` to `Any`, so this again may be a problem with how `mypy` handles `property`. `property` itself may not be correctly typed to handle the more precise typing in `Decorator`, and only when `property` is used "statically" as a decorator itself do the hints on `foo` carry through.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a very easy hack by doing this:

```py
import typing as t
import collections.abc as cx

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    F = t.TypeVar("F")
    Decorator: cx.Callable[[F], F]
else:
    class Decorator:
        """Your runtime implementation here"""
```

---

If you want to do this properly, it's a bit more verbose.

`property` is generally special-cased across all the type checker implementations. For `mypy`, you need to write anything that interacts with `property` as if `@property` was not even there. This means re-implementing `property`'s [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), if only for static type-checking purposes:

```py
import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t


Self = t.TypeVar("Self")
P = t.ParamSpec("P")
R = t.TypeVar("R", covariant=True)


class Decorator(t.Generic[P, R]):

    func: cx.Callable[P, R]

    def __init__(self, func: cx.Callable[P, R]) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
        # Type-check-only descriptor protocol access. No runtime implementation.
        @t.overload  # type: ignore[no-overload-impl]
        def __get__(self, instance: None, type_: type) -> property:
            """Descriptor access from the class (instance is `None`)"""

        @t.overload
        def __get__(self, instance: t.Any, type_: type) -> R:
            """Descriptor access from the instance"""


class Foo:
    @property
    @Decorator
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42


f = Foo()
# reveal_type(f.foo)  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
# reveal_type(Foo.foo)  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.property"
a: int = f.foo
print(a)
```

However, if I were you, I would write `class Decorator` to be completely independent of needing `property`. This means providing a runtime implementation to the descriptor protocol's `__get__`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t


ObjT = t.TypeVar("ObjT")
P = t.ParamSpec("P")
R = t.TypeVar("R", covariant=True)


class Decorator(t.Generic[P, R]):

    func: cx.Callable[P, R]

    def __init__(self, func: cx.Callable[P, R]) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    @t.overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, type_: type[ObjT]) -> Decorator[[ObjT], R]:
        ...

    @t.overload
    def __get__(self, instance: ObjT, type_: type[ObjT]) -> R:
        ...

    def __get__(
        self: Decorator[[ObjT], R], instance: ObjT | None, type_: type[ObjT]
    ) -> Decorator[[ObjT], R] | R:
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.func(instance)


class Foo:
    @Decorator
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return 42


f = Foo()
# reveal_type(f.foo)  # mypy: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
# reveal_type(Foo.foo)  # mypy: Revealed type is "Decorator[[call.Foo], builtins.int]"
a: int = f.foo
print(a)
```

Note that any descriptor-like access through the instance can only pass the instance object to `Decorator.func`; you can't have arbitrary arguments passed through `Foo().foo`, as Python's syntax doesn't allow you to do that.

The `Generic[P, R]` and `__call__` on `Decorator[...]` still allows you to use `@Decorator` over free functions (**not methods in class bodies**) which don't need `property`-like implementations, whatever your use case for that may be.